# How does one get from $\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigl( 1+ \frac{1}{3n} \bigr)^{2n}$ to $e^{2/3}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I want to know how one can find out that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigl( 1+ \frac{1}{3n} \bigr)^{2n} = e^{2/3}$$

I know that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigl(1 + \frac{x}{n} \bigr)^n = e^x$$

But which **"rule"** do we apply on the sequence above?

And why does this **not** work? If we say $\frac{1}{3n} \to 0$ with $n \to \infty$ because it's a null sequence.

Then  $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + 0)^{2n} = 1$ with $n \to \infty$

Comment: Consider the subsequence for $n' = 2n$. Then
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1+ \frac{1}{3n} \right)^{2n} = \lim_{ n' \to \infty} \left( 1+ \frac{1}{\frac{3n'}{2}} \right)^{n'} = \lim_{ n' \to \infty} \left( 1+ \frac{2/3}{n'} \right)^{n'} = e^{2/3}$$

Comment: Your approach doesn't work for the same reasons that $e^x\neq1$

Comment: @FShrike I understand Andreas solution now, but what do you mean with $e^x \neq 1$? The limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1^{2n} = 1$ and $e$ doesn't appear anywhere

Comment: Your approach doesn't work because $1^\infty$ is an indeterminate form. You can't just evaluate part of the limit and leave the rest for later

Comment: @Lorago Ah okay, sorry I didn't know it was indeterminate because an online calculator just said the limit was $1$ then. See https://www.symbolab.com/solver/limit-calculator/%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Cleft(1%5Cright)%5E%7B2n%7D?or=input

Comment: Your mistake there is that you can't just evaluate the part where $\frac{1}{3n}\to0$ while leaving the $2n$ in the exponent untouched. $n$ goes to $\infty$ at both those places *simultaneously*

Comment: If the substitutions confuse you, you could also note $ \bigl( 1+ \frac{1}{3n} \bigr)^{2n} = \bigl( \bigl(1+ \frac{1/3}{n} \bigr)^{n}\bigr)^2$...

Comment: $$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{3n}\right)^{2n}=\left(1+\dfrac{1}{3n}\right)^{2n(\frac{3n}{3n})}=\left(\left(1+\dfrac{1}{3n}\right)^{3n}\right)^{\frac{2n}{3n}}$$ so the exponent is 2/3 and what is below this exponent tends to $e$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u = 3n$.  Then

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{3n} \right)^{2n}$$
$$= \lim_{u \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{u} \right)^{(2/3)u}$$
$$= \left( \lim_{u \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{u} \right)^{u} \right)^{2/3} $$
$$= e^{2/3}$$

Answer (score 4):

More generally,

$\begin{array}\\
\left(1+\dfrac1{an}\right)^{bn}
&=\left(1+\dfrac1{an}\right)^{(b/a)an}\\
&=\left(\left(1+\dfrac1{an}\right)^{an}\right)^{b/a}\\
&\to e^{b/a}\\
\end{array}
$

Your case is
$a=3, b=2
$
so
$\frac{b}{a}=\frac23$
so the answer is
$e^{\frac23}
$.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^n = e^x$$

then compare that to the limit you have. First, the exponent is $2n$, so maybe we should try a substitution of $m=2n$. As $n\to\infty$, $m\to\infty$, and vice versa, so we get:

$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{x}{2m} \right)^{2m} = e^x$$

(And we can rename $m$ back to $n$ if we want.)

We're looking for a limit of $e^{2/3}$, so it should not come as a shock that $x=2/3$ will give us what we want:

$$e^{2/3}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{2/3}{2n} \right)^{2n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{3n} \right)^{2n}$$

---

To see why your argument that the limit is $1$ is faulty, consider this example:

(1) The limit of $n^n$ as $n\to 0$ is $0$, as we apply $n\to 0$ to the base to get $0^n$, which is $0$ (as $n\to 0$).

(2) The limit of $n^n$ as $n\to 0$ is $1$, as we apply $n\to 0$ to the exponent to get $n^0$, which is $1$ (as $n\to 0$).

But then $0=1$, which is clearly untrue! A limit cannot be equal to two different things.

The contradiction arises from not taking $n\to 0$ *simultaneously* for each instance of $n$ in the expression. Here, with $\lim_{n\to 0}n^n$, there is no defined limit, but in the case you give there *is* a limit. But the principle is the same: the variable $n$ is the same in both parts of the expression. Otherwise you are calculating:

$$ \lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{3n} \right)^{2m} $$

or:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{3n} \right)^{2m} $$